# Narrow column in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 2 column grid (actually, some rows have 2 columns in an otherwise 5 column grid). I'm trying to make the first one as narrow as possible and giving the rest of the length to the other. Nesting doesn't work because I only have 2 columns.

Basically, I want something like `col-xs-0.5` or better yet, solution that will make the first column just wide enough to fit the `*`

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/4jcL24ze/8/

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-1">*</div>
       <div class="col-xs-11">some long description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not add your own CSS that sets the width of the column to half or less of col-xs-1?

Comment: I can, but wanted to know if there is a solution within Bootstrap (otherwise, I can create my own css for the whole thing), specifically, so it would scale nicely as their class system scales

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Narrow Column**

You can use custom classes for your layout. Since `.col-xs-0.5` is half of `col-xs-1`, you can use `8.33/2 = 4.166%` and similarly subtract width from col-xs-11.5. But this is only for narrowing the column and is not needed if you need to fit the asterisk with the text description.

**Fitting `*` with the description**

I am not sure why you need to separate `*` to a new column when you can have it inside the text of `col-xs-12` like this: [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ez7zfLjp/)

```css
.col-xs-05, .col-xs-115 {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.col-xs-05 {
    width: 4.166%;
}
.col-xs-115 {
    width: 95.33%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-05">*</div>
       <div class="col-xs-115">some long description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4jcL24ze/1/)

Comment: I was looking for a solution within Bootstrap. Obviously I can create my own styles. But maybe that is the only solution

Comment: Yes, there is no out-of-the-box solution in Bootstrap. Nested columns will still occupy the width of the parent container.

Comment: Is there a way to just say: fit the contents exactly, leaving the rest to the other column? maybe it needs to be outside of the grid (but then how do I make sure they keep on the same line)?

Comment: Did you check my second paragraph? You need not have a grid for the `*` Just fit it inside the text of `col-xs-12` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ez7zfLjp/

Comment: Yes, I was simplifying. I have an icon there (from font-awesome) and would like the grid lines to show up.

Comment: So you want to replace the asterisk with an icon? Just get it inside along with the text and use `padding-left`